# Change the HTML tags of shop page in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm going to change the shop product title tag from H2 to H6. Please advise from which file these changes should be applied?

Summary:
sample.com/shop (this page)
h2-->h6

Comment: Which title? The individual product titles?

Answer (score 2):

## Update

As per your screenshot, you might want to do this using JavaScript/jQuery, since you're probably not using the default WooCommerce template. Hence, you can try the following snippet to achieve what you're looking for (I'm using jQuery here):

```
<script>

jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery("h2.woocommerce-loop-product__title").each(function(

        /* First we save the title */
        $saved_text = jQuery(this).text();

        /* Now we replace the tag */
        jQuery(this).replaceWith("<h6 class='woocommerce-loop-product__title'>"+ $saved_text + "</h6>");

    ));
    
});

</script>
```

*Note that I haven't been able to test the code. If you try this and it doesn't work or shows any issue, send me a screenshot and a small description of what steps have you taken to implement the code.*

---

---

---

First, you need to [create a child theme](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/) (if you don't have one already).

### If you want to edit the shop page's title tag:

Then add a folder named `woocommerce` in the child theme.

Go to `wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates` and copy the `archive-product.php` file to your child theme's ***woocommerce*** folder.

Now, edit the ***archive-product.php*** file that is inside your child theme's ***woocommerce*** folder:

Find line `34` and change the tag to h6.

The current line looks like this:

```
<h1 class="woocommerce-products-header__title page-title"><?php woocommerce_page_title(); ?></h1>
```

You'll change this line to this:

```
<h6 class="woocommerce-products-header__title page-title"><?php woocommerce_page_title(); ?></h6>
```

---

In rare occasion, if this doesn't work, create a ***functions.php*** file in your child theme unless you already have it, and in it, add the following:

```
add_action('after_setup_theme', 's_my_custom_woocommerce_support');

function s_my_custom_woocommerce_support(){
    add_theme_support( 'woocommerce' );
}
```

---

### If you want to change the title tag of individual products:

In your child theme, create a file called `functions.php` unless you already have it and in it, add the following:

```
//First we remove the current title
remove_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title','woocommerce_template_loop_product_title', 10 );

//then we add our title
add_action('woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 's_woocommerce_change_product_title_tags', 10 );

//here we define how our title looks
function s_woocommerce_change_product_title_tags() {
    echo '<h6 class="woocommerce-loop-product_title">' . get_the_title() . '</h6>';
}
```

> Make sure you're adding the code inside `<?php` and `?>`. Add these before and after the code if you're creating a brand new ***functions.php*** file.

However, please note that you can simply style the title using css classes and skip all these fuss, unless you absolutely need to change the tag (potentially for SEO or other purposes).

Comment: please look at this image https://pasteboard.co/JC2xuxo.png  i want change this h2 tags to h6

Comment: @AmirVaez It seems like a custom template by a page builder (Elementor/WP Bakery) or by the theme itself. It's difficult to say anything without knowing more details, because this is very specific to the themes, plugins, and their settings that you are using. However, there is a jQuery method, if you're interested. Check the **Update** section of the answer. If the answer helps you, please do mark it as the answer for the question. Thank you.